# Display datetime into MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm format c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

In database datetime is being stored in MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss fromat.
However, I want to display datetime in "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" format.
I tried it by using String.Format().

```
txtCampaignStartDate.Text = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy 
                           HH:mm}",appCampaignModel.CampaignStartDateTime);
```

Here `appCampaignModel.CampaignStartDateTime` is DateTime object having value in  **"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"**  format.

I want to display in  **"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"**  format.

Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: why not just replace the `-` with `/` ?

Comment: Don't store datetimes with a format which means that you store them as (n)varchar. Use `datetime` instead.

Comment: Is the datetime really stored as text, or is the datatype of the datetime field actually `datetime` and you just see it displayed like you do?

Comment: no,the field type is datetime only. I haven't taken it as varchar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The slashes in  this format `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm` mean: "replace me with the actual separator of the current culture". You have to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` explicitely:

```
txtCampaignStartDate.Text = appCampaignModel.CampaignStartDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[**The "/" Custom Format Specifier**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)

> In database datetime is being stored in MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss fromat.

Don't store `datetimes` with a format which means that you store them as `(n)varchar`. Use `datetime` instead.

Comment: Thanks Tim.:)It workes for me.And yeah I have taken datetime datatype only.

Answer (score 5):

```
txtCampaignStartDate.Text = appCampaignModel.CampaignStartDateTime
                                         .ToString().Replace("-","/");
```

or

```
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}", dt);
```

Check : [String Format for DateTime [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

or

```
String date = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

[DateTime.ToString Method (String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx)

Comment: I tried with String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt)  but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just a simple replace?

```
txtCampaignStartDate.Text = BadString.Replace("-","/");
```

Answer (score 1):

try using an added culture info:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
txtCampaignStartDate.Text = 
    appCampaignModel.CampaignStartDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", ci);
```

p.s. the culture info used is an example.

Answer (score 1):

To display your date in format you specified:

```
txtCampaignStartDate.Text = appCampaignModel.CampaignStartDateTime.ToString("g",DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

And for more date time formats you can go through this [link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a DateTime object, just ToString it how you want:

```
appCampaignModel.CampaignStartDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
```